# The enemy stops once it gets to a certain point, is there a way to adjust it so it stops doing that?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently replaced my movement script. However, my enemy now just goes to a certain point and then stops moving entirely.

- I was wondering If I could add or change anything to the code to make it so that it moves continuously while not chasing the player?

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class StalkerAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public Transform Player;

    public float range; //radius of sphere
    public Transform centrePoint; //centre of the area the agent wants to move around in
    //instead of centrePoint you can set it as the transform of the agent if you don't care about a specific area


    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distVal = 5.0f;
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(agent.transform.position, Player.position);

        if (dist <= distVal)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(Player.position);
        }
        else
        {
            if (agent.remainingDistance <= agent.stoppingDistance) //done with path
            {
                Vector3 point;
                if (RandomPoint(centrePoint.position, range, out point)) //pass in our centre point and radius of area
                {
                    Debug.DrawRay(point, Vector3.up, Color.blue, 1.0f); //so you can see with gizmos
                    agent.SetDestination(point);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    bool RandomPoint(Vector3 center, float range, out Vector3 result)
    {

        Vector3 randomPoint = center + Random.insideUnitSphere * range; //random point in a sphere 
        NavMeshHit hit;
        if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(randomPoint, out hit, 1.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas)) //documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.SamplePosition.html
        {
            //the 1.0f is the max distance from the random point to a point on the navmesh, might want to increase if range is big
            //or add a for loop like in the documentation
            result = hit.position;
            return true;
        }

        result = Vector3.zero;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: _"I decided to switch things up and use a different script that works well with a previous one (the one I was using before would not move even within range, and I got tired of using it)"_ - this doesn't tell us anything that is useful.  Consider rephrasing it.

Comment: _"I know this has been viewed 11 times and no one has said anything"_ - you gave the whole Stack Overflow community (at least those interested in `unity3d` and who are awake during these hours) a mere **1/2 hour** to respond.  Also, maybe those 11 people were _unable_ to help because they are not familiar with **A* Pathfinding** even if they are skilled in Unity in other areas.  Maybe they didn't understand your question, even those skilled in A*?  Maybe there is a problem with your question?  I know I found a problem.  Anyway, don't take it personally.  Go for a walk and come back later.

Comment: _"However, my enemy now just goes to a certain point and then `stops moving entirely` .... `I was wondering If I could add or change anything` to the code to make it so that it moves continuously while not chasing the player?"_ - considering you have encountered a bug the answer to your question is an obvious `yes` since a bug won't fix itself.   **You haven't actually explained the intended behaviour in sufficient detail**. [ask].  That is the reason for the down-votes I would expect.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the behavior you're looking for. Your problem was and probably the reason why you were downvoted was because you were passing a null vector3 to your RandomPoint Method.

If you had spent a couple minutes and read the comments in the code you would see exactly how to use it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class StalkerAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public Transform Player;

    public float range; //radius of sphere
    public Vector3 centrePoint; //centre of the area the agent wants to move around in
    //instead of centrePoint you can set it as the transform of the agent if you don't care about a specific area


    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distVal = 5.0f;
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(agent.transform.position, Player.position);

        if (dist <= distVal)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(Player.position);
        }
        else
        {
            if (agent.remainingDistance <= agent.stoppingDistance) //done with path
            {
                centrePoint = transform.position;

                if (RandomPoint(centrePoint, range, out centrePoint)) //pass in our centre point and radius of area
                {
                    Debug.DrawRay(centrePoint, Vector3.up, Color.blue, 1.0f); //so you can see with gizmos
                    agent.SetDestination(centrePoint);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    bool RandomPoint(Vector3 center, float range, out Vector3 result)
    {

        Vector3 randomPoint = center + Random.insideUnitSphere * range; //random point in a sphere
        NavMeshHit hit;
        if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(randomPoint, out hit, 1.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas)) //documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.SamplePosition.html
        {
            //the 1.0f is the max distance from the random point to a point on the navmesh, might want to increase if range is big
            //or add a for loop like in the documentation
            result = hit.position;
            return true;
        }

        result = Vector3.zero;
        return false;
    }

}
```